# Map numbers to characters

Tags: javascript, data-structures, permutation

I want to map this number "12145" to characters in this way

**12145->1,2,1,4,5->a,b,a,d,e**

*it also can be*

**12145->12,1,4,5->l,a,d,e**

*it can also be*

**12145->12,14,5->l,m,e**

and so on,

but 12145 can't be 1,2,1,45 because theres is no mapping for 45 in the alphabets .

Could any one explain a simple algorithm to to generate these permutations ?

Comment: is it homework?

Comment: What are the rules ? Why `1` is sometimes `a` and sometimes `1` ? Why `12345` becomes `12,14,5` ? What did you tried ?

Comment: not to mention 12345 -> 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: All the different solutions for a problem are called permutations. That may help you in finding a solution.

Comment: [How do I ask homework questions ?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: permutation would result in something like that 54121 but i want to keep same order just find all possible combinations of max 2 digits

Comment: First turn the number into a string,
then write a function that takes substrings of size 2 or 1,
so check 0 pairs, 1,2,3,4,5
then check 1 pair, 12,3,4,5  1,23,4,5  1,2,34,5  1,2,3,45
then check 2 pair  12,34,5   12, 3, 45    1, 23, 45 
basically this is a searching algorithm BFS or DFS should work
now map the values to of results to ints and convert those ints into letters with `String.fromCharCode()`

Comment: why do you have a single `1` in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

```
"12345"
```

So basically at first we want to to get substrings of our big number string, that are either one or two bytes long, so we start with one byte only:

```
 ["1", "2","3","4","5"]
```

Then we group two of them from left to right:

```
["12","3","4","5"]
["12","34","5"]
```

We continue with starting not at the beginning but at the second char:

```
["1","23","4","5"]
["1","23","45"]
```

We repeat this until grouping the last, and we should have all combinations:

```
 var val = (12345 +"").split("");//convert to string array
 var result = [val.slice(0)];

 //the start at loop:
for(var start = 0; start < val.length - 1; start++){
  //join groups one after each other:
  var grouped = [];
  for(var i = start; i < val.length - 1; i+=2){
    //group sth:
   grouped.push( val.slice(i,i+2).join("") );
   //generate the result:
  result.push( 
   val.slice(0,start).concat(//the numbers before the grouping
     grouped,//the grouped
     val.slice(i+2)) //after grouping
    );
 }
}
```

[You can try it here](http://jsbin.com/yohugebuni/edit?console)

The only thing you need to do now is to convert back to a number, filter out >26 ( or even better break the inner loop if the currently grouped is >26 ), and convert them to letters with:

```
 String.fromCharCode( number + 40 );
 //A is 41, B is 42, so number + 40 should do it
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get single numbers or double numbers and get their alphabet value.

It works with a recursive function `fork` with two parameters, `left` and `right`, whereas `left` is the given string and `right` is a temporary array for collecting part groups of valid numerical character representations.

At start of the function `fork`, an exit condition checks if all characters are distributed. In this case, where the length of the string `left` is 0, the temporary array right is converted to a letter string and pushed to the result set, as well as the function is returned, too.

The main part is basically the same, checking if a sub string value is valid, in terms of greater than zero and smaller or equal than 26, then the recursive function is called again with the string without the new substring and an array which contains the new sub string as well.

At the end, `result` contains all possible combinations.

```js
function getCombinations(string) {

    function fork(left, right) {
        if (!left.length) {
            result.push(right.map(function (v) { return (+v + 9).toString(36); }).join(''));
            return;
        }
        if (+left[0] > 0) {
            fork(left.slice(1), right.concat(left[0]));
        }
        if (left.length >= 2 && +(left.slice(0, 2)) <= 26) {
            fork(left.slice(2), right.concat(left.slice(0, 2)));
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(string, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombinations('12145'));
```